# Creating method to return Serilog LoggerConfiguration (Asp.Net Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I was initially using one log file for Serilog, which I accomplished by doing this

```
var slc = new SerilogSubLoggerConfiguration();   
configuration.GetSection("Serilog:SubLogger").Bind(slc);
```

and then configuring the SubLogger in the Main method of Program.cs

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .WriteTo.Logger(logger => logger.Filter.
                ByIncludingOnly(lvl => lvl.Level == slc.Level).WriteTo.RollingFile(slc..PathFormat))
            .CreateLogger();
```

I have moved to using three separate logs now defined in the appsettings file.
This creates the class, with one property, a list of Serilog configurations

```
 public class SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations
{
    public List<SerilogSubLoggerConfiguration> SubLoggers { get; set; }
}

var slcs = configuration.GetSection("Serilog").Get<SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations>();
```

Now that I have my list of SubLogger configs, I need to create the logger, and add all these sub loggers. Each SubLogger will need its own

```
.WriteTo.Logger(logger => logger.Filter.
                ByIncludingOnly(lvl => lvl.Level == slc.Level).WriteTo.RollingFile(slc..PathFormat))
```

line in the Log.Logger call, therefore I need to iterate over the SubLoggers.
My intention was to write a method to do so.

```
public static LoggerConfiguration GetLoggerConfiguration(IConfiguration config, SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations slcs)
    {
        var lc = new LoggerConfiguration();
        lc.ReadFrom.Configuration(config);

        foreach (var cfg in slcs.SubLoggers)
        {
            lc.WriteTo.Logger(logger => logger.Filter
                                       .ByIncludingOnly(lvl => lvl.Level == cfg.Level).WriteTo
                                       .RollingFile(cfg.PathFormat));
        }

        lc.CreateLogger();
        return lc;
    }
```

and then just use this in the Main method

```
Log.Logger = GetLoggerConfiguration(configuration, slcs);
```

But this errs,

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Serilog.LoggerConfiguration' to 'Serilog.ILogger'

I tried changing the method to an ILogger and returning an ILogger, but ILogger doesn't contain the WriteTo and ReadFrom methods, so that was a no go.
I tried casting the returned LoggerConfiguration to an ILogger, but that didn't work either and a number of other iterations that also failed.

There must be a way to accomplish this. Any help appreciated.

**Update:**

```
 public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currentEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{currentEnv}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        var slcs = configuration.GetSection("Serilog").Get<SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations>();
        Log.Logger = BuildLogger(configuration, slcs);
        Log.Information(Appname != null ? $"{Appname}{LogDelimeter}Logger created." : "Logger created.");

        try
        {
            Log.Information(Appname != null ? $"{Appname}{LogDelimeter}Starting web host" : "Starting web host.");
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex,
                Appname != null
                    ? $"{Appname}{LogDelimeter}Web Host terminated unexpectedly"
                    : "Web Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {

            Log.Information(Appname != null ? $"{Appname}{LogDelimeter}Flushing log and closing it." : "Flushing log and closing it.");
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried changing the method to an ILogger and returning an ILogger,
>   but ILogger doesn't contain the WriteTo and ReadFrom methods, so that
>   was a no go.

The sequence of Serilog bootstraping is following:

1. You create an instance of `Serilog.LoggerConfiguration` object and setup it with either code calls (`WriteTo.RollingFile()`) or from config files (`ReadFrom.Configuration()`).
2. Then after Serilog configuration is built, you create a logger with `LoggerConfiguration.CreateLogger()` call.

So before you finished loading configuration you can't log any messages (you don't have `Logger` instance yet). But after you built a logger there is no point to call `WriteTo` or `ReadFrom` methods since logger is already built and changes to source configuration will not affect anything.

So you could change your `GetLoggerConfiguration()` method as:

```
public static Serilog.ILogger BuildLogger(IConfiguration config, SerilogSubLoggerConfigurations slcs)
{
    var lc = new LoggerConfiguration();
    lc.ReadFrom.Configuration(config);

    foreach (var cfg in slcs.SubLoggers)
    {
        lc.WriteTo.Logger(logger => logger.Filter
            .ByIncludingOnly(lvl => lvl.Level == cfg.Level).WriteTo
            .RollingFile(cfg.PathFormat));
    }

    //  Apply any additional changes to lc configuration here

    //  Finally build a logger
    return lc.CreateLogger();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //  ...
    var logger = BuildLogger(configuration, subLoggerConfigurations);

    //  No any changes could be made to logging configuration at this point.
    //  Just log what you need.

    logger.Information("Test info message");
}
```

Comment: @CodeFuller...since I am not a professional programmer, I am not seeing why  lc.CreateLogger(); return lc; is any different than return lc.CreateLogger();  because I had tried making my method a static ILogger and I was getting an error on return lc;

Comment: Also, since you are an expert in Serilog, why does this code section in Main try-catch-finally;                                                                                        
           finally  {
                
                Log.Information(Appname != null ? $"{Appname}{LogDelimeter}Flushing log and closing it." : "Flushing log and closing it.");
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }      in my Main method, not produce a log message when the application is closed? It appears the logger is not disposed on application close?

Comment: `Log.Information()` method will work only if you set `Log.Logger` property: `Log.Logger = BuildLogger(configuration, subLoggerConfigurations);`

Comment: Log.Information() calls work everywhere in the application. I'm just wondering why when the application is closed I do not get the log message that the log is closed and flushed. any thoughts on my first comment on return lc;

Comment: Regarding first comment, `lc.CreateLogger(); return lc;` returns object of `LoggerConfiguration` type, you don't actually use `Logger` object created by `CreateLogger()` call.

Comment: Regarding problem of `Log.Information()` in `finally` block, could you update your question with exact body of your `Main()` method? Little things could matter here.

Comment: It works fine for me, `Flushing log and closing it` message appears in the log. Try setting breakpoint and check whether it hits. `BuildWebHost(args).Run();` will actually run web host and control flow will not get to finally block untill host is shut down or some exception happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160338/discussion-between-dinotom-and-codefuller).